# How to replace string with dictionary in Python?

Tags: python

How to change the `string` to `result`?

```
string = 'John and Mary are good friends'
d = {'John': 'Sam', 'Mary': 'Ann', 'are': 'are not'}

result = 'Sam and Ann are not good friends'
```

Thank you.

Comment: Is a list of possible names supplied? I see you have 'Sam' and 'Ann' in the output, but not the input. This sounds like graph theory. Are you trying to find nodes that aren't directly connected?

Comment: We would like to see your effort in solving the problem next time

Answer (score 5):

If keys in dictionary have only one word is possible split, map by `get` and `join` back:

```
a = ' '.join(d.get(x, x) for x in string.split())
print (a)
Sam and Ann are not good friends
```

If possible multiple words and also is necessary use words boundaries for avoid replace substrings:

```
import re

string = 'John and Mary are good friends'
d = {'John and': 'Sam with', 'Mary': 'Ann', 'are good': 'are not'}

pat = '|'.join(r"\b{}\b".format(x) for x in d.keys())
a = re.sub(pat, lambda x: d.get(x.group(0)), string)
print (a) 
Sam with Ann are not friends
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
string = 'John and Mary are good friends'
d = {'John': 'Sam', 'Mary': 'Ann', 'are': 'are not'}

result = string

for key, value in d.items():
    result = result.replace(key, value)

print(result)

output:
Sam and Ann are not good friends
```

Comment: Does Python have any function or package for that instead of using for loop?

Comment: @John What's wrong with using a for loop?

Answer (score 0):

1 - Iterate over each word of string.

2 - check if word exists in dictionary keys.

3 - If it does exist append **value** of that word to result. if it does not, append **word** to result.

Answer (score 0):

Basic approach:

1. split the long string into a list of words
2. iterate through this list of words; if any word exists as a key in the given dictionary, replace that word with the corresponding value from the dictionary
3. join the list of words together using space

```
string = 'John and Mary are good friends'
d = {'John': 'Sam', 'Mary': 'Ann', 'are': 'are not'}

s = string.split()
for i, el in enumerate(s):
    if el in d:
        s[i] = d[el]
print(' '.join(s))
```

Comment: Please don't only post code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. That will make your answer more valuable and is more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel thanks for the advice - I've updated the answer.